# Remove other shipping methods from cart if free shipping is available?

Tags: cart, magento-1, free-shipping

If the cart has items with a value over $100, the customer gets free shipping. I removed all other shipping methods from the checkout by following http://projectamplify.com/insight/remove-magento-shipping-methods-if-free-shipping-available/.

There it says, it will also work for the cart, but it is not. The cart still shows the wrong shipping (the one for carts under $100).

How can I change that so that I see free shipping in cart, too if value is over $100?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's right, this method only removes the option from the checkout. On the cart when no option is selected yet, it does not change anything.

If it's an option for you, set up a *shopping cart promotional rule* instead of the "free shipping" method. It will make all shipping methods cost 0 if the rule conditions are met (condition based on item value are possible). These rules are applied on the cart page already.